# Custom command on elastic beanstalk prompts invalid syntax in manage.py file

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to figure out how to best call a script with cronjobs and am unable to figure it out. Either I go with a custom command where I use the following in .ebextension/"some config file":

```
container_commands:
  01_some_cron_job:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/some_cron_job.txt > /etc/cron.d/mycron && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/mycron"
    leader_only: true
```

some_cron_job.txt:

```
* * * * * root source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env && /usr/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py cron_command >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

This works when i run the command locally but after having uploaded it to eb I get the following error:

> File "/opt/python/current/app/manage.py", line 18
>       ) from exc
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Or I could call the script directly:

```
* * * * * root source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env && /usr/bin/python /opt/python/current/app/api/cron.py >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

But am then getting import errors when trying to import a function from a another file in the same directory:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I'm quite lost and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a working solution where I instead used:

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/mycron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      0/10 * * * * root source /opt/python/current/env && /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3 /opt/python/current/app/manage.py cron_command >> /var/log/newjob.log 2>&1

commands:
    remove_old_cron:
        command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/mycron.bak"
```

I think the problem came about because of some python version problems in the virtual environment.